# How can I get cpb fullness information from h.265 encoded bit stream?

Tags: video, video-processing, hevc, h.265

My job is to plot a graph of cpb fullness v/s time. But I am not able to get cpb fullness information. Can anyone suggest me where to look for it in the HM reference code ?

Comment: `Coded Picture Buffer` is the job for the Rate-Controller. Have you had a look in `source/Lib/TLibEncoder/TEncRateCtrl.cpp`?

Comment: @FredrikPihl actually I have to get that information from an encoded bit stream. so, I was looking it from decoder point of view.

Comment: @FredrikPihl Can HRD Parameters be of any help?